# Does Chinese have an equivalent to “Person A”?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

In English, sometimes we'll refer to a person whose name is unknown or undisclosed as "Person A" particularly in hypothetical scenarios. Does a similar thing exist in Chinese that doesn't make use of English letters?

Comment: Some other alternatives: 某甲，某乙，etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would say

> 甲、乙、丙、丁……

which come from [天干](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A9%E5%B9%B2), you could also say

> 路人甲、路人乙、路人丙……

If you know the person's surname, you could also say

> 李某、王某……

In case if you want the specify that person's occupation

> 某市民、某员工、某政府工作人员……

Comment: what about 小明，小刚，小红，李华

Comment: @rambler Those would almost be real name and nicknames, which can be commonly used in simple short made up stories.

Answer (score 6):

To refer to someone non-specific, you can say「某某/某人/某某人」.

> 我廠「某人」偷了東西，我不點他的名字，他應坦白交代。
>
> ***Someone*** in my factory was stealing things. I won't mention him by name, but he should come forth honestly and explain himself.

To refer to *Person A* or *Party A*, for example in an agreement or contract, you can say 「甲方」(as opposed to *Person/Party B*「乙方」or *both parties*「雙方」).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to those involving 某, as explained in other answers, there are some general names used quite often (e.g. in story-telling) like 张三 and 李四.

The complete list goes as: 刘一、陈二、张三、李四、王五、赵六、孙七、周八、吴九、郑十

Source: https://www.zhihu.com/question/63926768

Comment: Btw, I think this is the equivalent of _John Doe_ (and _Jane Doe_) used in English.

Answer (score 2):

有个人。 means someone/somebody whom you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce two things:

> 天干 (Celestial Stems):
>
> 甲 乙 丙 丁 戊 己 庚 辛 壬 癸

and

> 地支 (Terrestrial Branches):
>
> 子 丑 寅 卯 辰 巳 午 未 申 酉 戌 亥

These two things are often used for these purposes.

---

**Example 1**

> 某甲 person A
>
> 某乙 person B

**Example 2**

> 甲型肝炎 (甲肝) hepatitis A
>
> 乙型肝炎 (乙肝) hepatitis B
>
> 丙型肝炎 hepatitis C
>
> 丁型肝炎 hepatitis D

**Example 3**

> 甲型超声波 ultrasound A
>
> 乙型超声波 (B超)  ultrasound B

**Example 4**

> 甲烷 methane
>
> 乙烷 ethane
>
> 丙烷 propane
>
> 丁烷 butane
>
> 戊烷 pentane
>
> 己烷 hexane
>
> 庚烷 heptane
>
> 辛烷 octane
>
> 壬烷 nonane
>
> 癸烷 decane

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it does. The most famous unknown person A is "张三" in Chinese.